# I can not create apk on Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, linux, gradle, raspberry-pi, android-sdk-tools

I try to create apk using the terminal on my raspebrry pi b+ but each time we display this error:

```
    pi@raspberrypi /var/www/html/app-get/newapplication $ sudo ./gradlew assembleDebug
:mobile:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:mobile:preFlossDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:mobile:checkFlossDebugManifest
:mobile:preFlossReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:mobile:preGplayDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:mobile:preGplayReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:mobile:prepareComAmulyakhareComAmulyakhareTextdrawable101Library UP-TO-DATE
:mobile:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library
Support for reading or changing file permissions is only available on this platform using Java 7 or later.
:mobile:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72103Library
:mobile:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library
:mobile:prepareComMelnykovFloatingactionbutton130Library
:mobile:prepareFlossDebugDependencies
:mobile:compileFlossDebugAidl
:mobile:compileFlossDebugRenderscript
:mobile:generateFlossDebugBuildConfig
:mobile:generateFlossDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mobile:mergeFlossDebugAssets
:mobile:generateFlossDebugResValues
:mobile:generateFlossDebugResources
:mobile:mergeFlossDebugResourcesAAPT err(Facade for 17718085): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 12465622): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 11142540): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 14213640): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 21726721): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 30470707): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 30057086): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 8572351): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 10208178): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 14197974): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 12422350): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 7208668): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 1607509): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 25709829): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 1731843): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_4" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_5" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_3" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
AAPT err(Facade for 20855356): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 28455207): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 2084630): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 9663360): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 32500053): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_10" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_8" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_9" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_6" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_7" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_11" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_14" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_13" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_15" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_12" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_16" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_20" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_18" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_19" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_17" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In the raspberry pi I installed openjdk 8 instead of Oracle JDK because I could not install.
I tried the same application on a different Windows PC and android studio and it worked without problems.

Know someone how to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 1):

The "Timed out" messages are really just saying that the work we were waiting for failed. These are the interesting errors:

```
AAPT err(Facade for 12465622): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 11142540): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 14213640): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 21726721): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 30470707): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 30057086): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 8572351): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 10208178): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 14197974): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 12422350): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 7208668): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 1607509): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 25709829): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
AAPT err(Facade for 1731843): /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

To save you some horizontal scrolling, they all say `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`.

Looking at [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/android-6.0.0_r26/build-system/builder/src/main/java/com/android/builder/png/AaptProcess.java), we can see that AaptProcess communicates with a long-running `aapt` child process through stdin/stdout.

I *think* the "Syntax error" message is coming from that communication.

To verify this, you can run the `aapt` tool manually. Use an arg of `m` to get into the (undocumented, as far as I can tell?) interactive mode. Then, a png crunch command consists of three lines: `s`, `infilepath`, `outfilepath`. It'll look something like this:

```
~$ /home/snild/.androidsdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt m
Ready
s
/tmp/icon.png
/tmp/icon-crunched.png
Crunching /tmp/icon.png
Crunching single PNG file: /tmp/icon.png
    Output file: /tmp/icon-crunched.png
Done
s
/tmp/icon2.png
/tmp/icon2-crunched.png
Crunching /tmp/icon2.png
Crunching single PNG file: /tmp/icon2.png
    Output file: /tmp/icon2-crunched.png
Done
```

This works fine for me, but I'm running on my laptop. It'd be interesting to see if this works on your Raspberry Pi.

*Update 1:* It didn't.

```
$ sudo /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt m
/mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`
```

That means that there's nothing weird with your PNG paths, because aapt never gets that far. Next, let's try to narrow down the problem by checking if it can do anything at all. Try running it without the m parameter -- it should print some documentation; does it? Try running aapt list something.apk, does that work? strace aapt m and ltrace aapt m may give some clues.

*Update 2:* It still failed the same way, even without the "m" arg. The strace and ltrace invokes were more informative:

```
$ strace /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt
execve("/mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt", ["/mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/buil"..., "m"], [/* 19 vars */]) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
write(2, "strace: exec: Exec format error\n", 32strace: exec: Exec format error ) = 32
exit_group(1) = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++

$ ltrace /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt
"/mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt" is ELF from incompatible architecture
```

This means that the `aapt` binary you have is compiled for an incompatible architecture (maybe x86/Intel, or just a newer ARM instruction set). You can use `file /path/to/aapt` to get some details on the executable. Compare this to something that you know is working on your system, for example `file /bin/bash`. You should see that they're different.

In any case, the conclusion is that you have downloaded build tools that are not compatible with your platform (the Raspberry Pi). I'm not sure if there are any official downloads for the ARM architecture. You could try compiling the tools yourself, or try to find the suitable binaries for download somewhere.

Comment: Outcome : `sudo /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt m` is :
`/mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: Okay, so that means that there's nothing weird with your PNG paths, because `aapt` never gets that far. Next, let's try to narrow down the problem by checking if it can do anything at all. Try running it without the `m` parameter -- it should print some documentation; does it? Try running `aapt list something.apk`, does that work? `strace aapt m` and `ltrace aapt m` may give some clues. Otherwise, we're getting to the point where you're going to have to run it in gdb and try to figure out where that error message comes from.

Comment: Outcome (All) : `/mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: 1: /mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: That's all, even for the strace and ltrace ones?

Comment: strace : `execve("/mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt", ["/mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/buil"..., "m"], [/* 19 vars */]) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
write(2, "strace: exec: Exec format error\n", 32strace: exec: Exec format error
) = 32
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++ ` 
ltrace: `"/mnt/sda1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt" is ELF from incompatible architecture
`

Comment: Ah. Your `aapt` program is compiled for an incompatible architecture (maybe x86/Intel, or just a newer ARM instruction set). You can use `file /path/to/aapt` to get some details on the executable. Compare this to something that you know is working on your system, for example `file /bin/bash`. You should see that they're different. In any case, the conclusion is that you have downloaded build tools that are not compatible with your platform (the Raspberry Pi). I'm not sure if there are any official downloads for the ARM arch. You could try compiling the tools yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll update my answer with some cleaned-up info from our comments here, in case other people have the same issue and find their way here.